# Show AdSense ads on another website based on interactions on my Blog

Tags: ads, google-tag-manager, adsense, google-ads-api

I have a blog with some sponsored posts.

If a user visits a post linked to a sponsor, I want to show up AdSense ads related with that sponsor on other websites (Which use AdSense) for visitors who have recently visited my site.

Is this possible using Dynamic Remarketing? I know I can show tailored ads using Google Tag Manager, Dynamic Remarketing and Adwords... I want to do something similar with AdSense but apparently, there is not relation between Dynamic Remarketing and Adsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adsense is a technology for implementing ads on websites. You are right, there is no direct relation between Adsense and Remarketing. But Adsense will show all kinds of ads, remarketing or not.

So if you want your ads to appear within Adsense you can just simply select "Display network" in Adwords to make your ads appear only within adsense (and all other display networks within Googles reach). You even can select the website you want your ads to appear.

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2470108?hl=en